# Postfix server receiving backscatter and blacklists

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I have woke up to one of my clients receiving a lot backscatter and my ip placed on two blacklists!

Is there anything I can do I have tried altering my `header_checks` (see below) which has made no difference.

Finally I am very confused as to why I have been put on a blacklist when they are not sending these emails from my server!!

My configs are as follow (sorry about so much info and please let me know if you see any other issues with the config or things you may do differently):

## main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = mail.$myhostname ESMTP mail.$mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks
        permit_sasl_authenticated
        defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
myhostname = mail.foo.info
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
milter_protocol = 6
milter_default_action = accept
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
virtual_minimum_uid = 100
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
message_size_limit = 52428800
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_unknown_client_hostname, sleep 3, reject_unauth_pipelining
```

## header_checks:

```
/^Subject:.*viagra.*/ REJECT
/^Subject:.*pills.*/ REJECT
/^Subject:.*F\*ckbuddy.*/ REJECT
/^Subject:.*F\*ckfriend.*/ REJECT
/^Subject:.*f\@ck.*/ REJECT

/^From:.*viagra.*/ REJECT

#block blackscatter
if /^Received:/
/^Received: +from +(hostname\.co\.uk) +/
        reject forged client name in Received: header: $1
/^Received: +from +[^ ]+ +\(([^ ]+ +[he]+lo=|[he]+lo +)(hostname\.co\.uk)\)/
        reject forged client name in Received: header: $2
/^Received:.* +by +(hostname\.co\.uk)\b/
        reject forged mail server name in Received: header: $1
endif
/^Message-ID:.* <!&!/ DUNNO
/^Message-ID:.*@(hostname\.co\.uk)/
        reject forged domain name in Message-ID: header: $1
```

## master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

---

Backscatter looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/YAFbd3Pq)

Blacklisted on:

- TRUNCATE
- Protected Sky

<sub>Please note that `foo.info`, `clientdomain.com` and `hostname.co.uk` all link up to my config files appropriately</sub>

Comment: Both TRUNCATE and Protected Sky do give reasons for listing. You should at least query them yourself and analyze the result. Better yet, tell us the actual domain this is about and the IP address of the blacklisted server so we can have a look.

Comment: That spam was sent by an authenticated user of your mail service, through your mail server. Either the user's credentials were stolen or their computer was compromised.

Comment: @Michael Hampton jesus really? Any help on identifying it? I changed julie@clientdomain.com password and ran `postsuper -d ALL deferred`  but it still carried on!

Comment: @Michael Hampton also how do you know that?

Comment: I can't say for sure because you insist against our advice in obfuscating essential information in your backscatter specimen, but it looks very much like it's your own server that is producing the would-be backscatter while trying to send out spam to non-existent addresses. That would also explain why it is blacklisted. You need to analyze how these mails are injected into your server using the real log data.

Comment: it seems to be root@hostname.co.uk who is sending all the emails!!

Comment: How did you arrive at that conclusion? It seems quite improbable to me, but if it is, you're hosed and you better reinstall that server from scratch with the help of someone who knows about IT security.

Comment: well it has 1.2GB worth of new emails? which seems rediculous

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt can I email you the unobfuscated version?

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt would you be able to help out? Pretty scared.

Comment: You need to have someone who knows about mail server administration and security have an unobstructed look on your server. I cannot be that someone. I am too far away and I have a full time job to handle. I'm glad to help out with answers to specific questions that fall into my expertise, but I have no free capacity for remote consulting.